# CarrierWave TypeError (can't dump File) on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave

In development, Fog/S3 upload works fine with CarrierWave. In production, I keep seeing this error:

I've seen this on other Stack Overflow posts, but they were about multi-part forms. Mine is just a regular file field inside of a standard form. I use ActiveRecord's session_store (now a separate gem), and it looks like it's having a hard time dumping the file but I'm not sure why that is. Here's the full stack trace:

```
2014-11-24T17:33:04.682703+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DefendantsController#update as HTML
2014-11-24T17:33:04.682795+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bhvn+IUv3Vw7OReBDDE97YZuRBBSs9bGQ6K1xvkTBpQ=", "defendant"=>{"organization_id"=>"2", "picture_attributes"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fdaab19c700 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141124-2-65sl86>, @original_filename="avatar.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"defendant[picture_attributes][image]\"; filename=\"avatar.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "name"=>"john doe", "nickname_or_alias"=>"", "marital_status"=>"Single", "maiden_name"=>"", "birthday"=>"02/24/1984", "email"=>"blah@blah.com", "weight"=>"150", "height"=>"72", "skin_color"=>"White", "eye_color"=>"Brown", "gender"=>"Male", "race"=>"Caucasian", "hair_color"=>"Black", "scar_or_tattoo"=>"", "spouse_name"=>"", "facebook_url"=>"", "united_states_citizen"=>"1", "ssn"=>"000-11-1111"}, "commit"=>"Update Defendant", "id"=>"2"}
2014-11-24T17:33:04.680411+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PATCH "/defendants/2" for 68.53.142.146 at 2014-11-24 17:33:04 +0000
2014-11-24T17:33:05.543253+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 860ms (ActiveRecord: 15.0ms)
2014-11-24T17:33:05.542976+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://bailbetter.herokuapp.com/defendants/2/edit
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549278+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549283+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError (can't dump File):
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549284+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-0.1.0/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:7:in `dump'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-0.1.0/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:7:in `marshal'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549288+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-0.1.0/lib/active_record/session_store/session.rb:73:in `marshal_data!'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549289+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549294+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549295+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549296+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549315+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549316+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549318+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549319+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549320+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549322+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549323+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549324+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549325+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549327+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549328+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549329+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549331+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549332+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-0.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb:80:in `block in set_session'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549333+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in quietly'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549335+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:48:in `silence_stream'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549336+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:105:in `block in quietly'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549337+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:48:in `silence_stream'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549338+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:104:in `quietly'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549340+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-0.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb:77:in `set_session'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549341+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:342:in `commit_session'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549342+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `context'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549343+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549345+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549346+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549352+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549353+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549354+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549356+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549357+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549358+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549359+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549361+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549362+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549363+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549364+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549365+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549367+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549369+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549370+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549372+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.553984+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/defendants/2" host=bailbetter.herokuapp.com request_id=dc9adbf1-78de-48aa-b913-4b0f59992c0b fwd="68.53.142.146" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=978ms status=500 bytes=1497
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549373+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549376+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549377+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549378+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549379+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549380+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549382+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549383+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549384+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549386+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549388+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549389+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549391+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549392+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549393+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549394+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549396+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549398+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549399+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549400+00:00 app[web.1]:   bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549401+00:00 app[web.1]:   bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549402+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-24T17:33:05.549403+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-24T17:36:16.832243+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.87.115.122 at 2014-11-24 17:36:16 +0000
2014-11-24T17:36:16.841057+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
2014-11-24T17:36:16.842255+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_errors.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-11-24T17:36:16.842361+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-11-24T17:36:16.842586+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-11-24T17:36:16.835923+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
2014-11-24T17:36:16.841969+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-11-24T17:36:16.843465+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-11-24T17:36:16.856746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bailbetter.herokuapp.com request_id=2624573d-1670-45d5-945d-13cbe8b99285 fwd="54.87.115.122" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=4321
2014-11-24T17:40:46.930531+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.211.161.144 at 2014-11-24 17:40:46 +0000
2014-11-24T17:40:46.937803+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
2014-11-24T17:40:46.933689+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
2014-11-24T17:40:46.938622+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (0.7ms)
2014-11-24T17:40:46.938908+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_errors.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-11-24T17:40:46.939009+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-11-24T17:40:46.939212+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-11-24T17:40:46.940133+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-11-24T17:40:46.953041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bailbetter.herokuapp.com request_id=9a530552-a3bc-4401-a1b6-cc5736cd0c0b fwd="54.211.161.144" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=4321
2014-11-24T17:50:59.689993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bailbetter.herokuapp.com request_id=8cecda20-c0b9-48ac-b271-ab6d88deade7 fwd="54.90.222.139" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4321
2014-11-24T17:50:59.671966+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 54.90.222.139 at 2014-11-24 17:50:59 +0000
2014-11-24T17:50:59.678050+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
2014-11-24T17:50:59.678987+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_errors.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-11-24T17:50:59.679373+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-11-24T17:50:59.674640+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
2014-11-24T17:50:59.678713+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (0.5ms)
2014-11-24T17:50:59.679143+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-11-24T17:50:59.680198+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And here is the controller action:

```
  def update
    @defendant = Defendant.find(params[:id])
    convert_params

    unless @defendant.update_attributes(sanitized_params)
      flash[:notice] = @defendant.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    end

    redirect_to edit_defendant_path(@defendant)
  end

  private

    def sanitized_params
      params.require(:defendant).permit(
        :organization_id, :name, :maiden_name, :birthday, 
        :email, :weight, :height, :skin_color,
        :eye_color, :gender, :race, :hair_color,
        :scar_or_tattoo, :spouse_name, :facebook_url, :nickname_or_alias,
        :marital_status, :united_states_citizen, :ssn,
        picture_attributes: [
          :image
        ]
      )
    end

    def convert_params
      params[:defendant][:birthday] = convert_date_string(params[:defendant][:birthday])
    end
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the initializer I'm using for Carrierwave:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
  end
else
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',    
      :aws_access_key_id      => Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,    
      :aws_secret_access_key  => Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key,   
      :region                 => 'us-east-1'
    }
    config.fog_directory  = "myapp-#{Rails.env}"
  end
end

if Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.enable_processing = false
  end

  PictureUploader

  CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
    next if klass.anonymous?
    klass.class_eval do
      def cache_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/tmp"
      end

      def store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the uploader itself:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  # storage :fog
  # DECLARED IN INITIALIZER

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path([version_name || "picture", "placeholder.png"].compact.join('_'))

    # "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  process resize_to_fit: [500, 500]

  version :thumbnail do
    process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Here's the Defendant model:

```
class Defendant < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DateHelper
  paginates_per 10
  acts_as_paranoid
  attr_encrypted :ssn, key: 'mykeygoeshere', encode: true
  normalize_attribute :nickname_or_alias, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :marital_status, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :maiden_name, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :email, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :weight, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :height, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :skin_color, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :eye_color, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :race, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :hair_color, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :scar_or_tattoo, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :spouse_name, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :facebook_url, with: :blank
  normalize_attribute :ssn, with: :blank

  attr_accessor :forward_to_bond_creation

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :bonds
  has_many :court_dates
  has_many :payments
  has_one :picture
  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:image].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes.except(:phoneable_id).all?(&:blank?) }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes.except(:addressable_id).all?(&:blank?) }

  validates_presence_of :organization, :name, :birthday, :gender
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, allow_nil: true
  validates_format_of :ssn, :with => /\A(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4})\Z/, allow_nil: true
  validates_format_of :facebook_url, :with => /facebook.com/, allow_nil: true

  def behind_with_payments?
    !!(payment_status =~ "behind_with_payments")
  end

  def current_with_payments?
    !!(payment_status =~ "current_with_payments")
  end

  def payment_status
    if bonds.behind_with_payments.any?
      "behind_with_payments"
    else
      "current_with_payments"
    end
  end

  def picture_url
    if picture
      picture.image.url
    else
      ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("picture_placeholder.png")
    end
  end

  def thumbnail_url
    if picture
      picture.image.thumbnail.url
    else
      ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("thumbnail_placeholder.png")
    end
  end

  def as_json options={}
    options.merge({ id: id, name: name, birthday: format_date(birthday), thumbnail_url: thumbnail_url })
  end
end
```

And here is the Picture model:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid

  belongs_to :defendant

  mount_uploader :image, PictureUploader
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

I removed the `activerecord-session_store` gem, thinking that may be the problem since that's where the error was happening. I also added this line that supposedly helped others in similar situations (despite my best instincts, since the image isn't being saved, I knew it wasn't only erring just before the redirect, but I tried anway):

```
params[:defendant][:picture_attributes][:image].tempfile = nil
```

And even with both of these fixes, I get the same error:

```
2014-11-25T19:49:39.916837+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError (can't dump File):
2014-11-25T19:49:39.916842+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:418:in `serialize'
2014-11-25T19:49:39.916839+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:418:in `dump'
...
```

Comment: You must use a multipart form if you are submitting a file. This is the purpose of `multipart/form-data`. Also I really hope you plan on encrypting this heavily since you are passing a `ssn`. For Reference here is [W3 information about multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Comment: @engineersmnky indeed, the SSN is encrypted :) and I didn't realize that. Thanks a ton! I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @engineersmnky that didn't fix it :/

Comment: According to some very quick googling it seems that you will need to set the file object to nil before redirecting. something like `params[:defendant][:picture_attributes][:image] = nil` before redirecting seems to be the proposed work around. [Reference](http://www.freezzo.com/2008/06/18/rails-typeerror-cant-dump-file/). There are a whole lot more or the same out there. Seems to have something to do with caching the file and that it is too large to store.

Comment: @engineersmnky I saw that, but I'm unsure if my problem is the same. I'm not caching a file.. And the error happens before the redirect (if it happened after the redirect, the image would already be saved at least, but it's not).

Comment: Can you add your model that is handling this then because it does not seem to be a controller issue at that point.

Comment: @engineersmnky Added it above

Comment: @engineersmnky also tried your suggestions, added the results. see above

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone else... I tried uploading an image in console and realized my AWS key was getting set to:

```
ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
```

Aka my secrets.yml file looked like:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

Hence all the errors. Changed it in my secrets.yml file to:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
```

Now we're all good. Sorry guys, thanks a ton!

Comment: that makes sense because it passes through the `erb` before `YAML`.

Comment: @engineersmnky ya it was just reading what i had as raw strings, not grabbing the actual ENV vars.

Comment: Also just because I noticed how you are testing rather than creating a bunch of useless files for testing on your local disk. Take a look at [Mocking Fog](https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/mocking-fog-when-using-it-with-carrierwave). Doing things this way has cleaned up our testing environment a lot.